# Number three plug fouling days after I put it in

Tags: misfire, saturn, spark

The number 3 plug is fouling on my 99 Saturn sw2 days after I put it in and the car is throwing misfire codes as well as near stall code can anyone get me a answer why its fouling so fast could it be my coil pack??

Comment: Was this just a normal tune up? Why did you change out the plugs in the first place? How many miles on the car?

Comment: It has 240,000 on the car and it was just a normal tune up the number three plug was fouled and the car has a bad misfire after warming up

Comment: It doesn't misfire while it's cold? How long does it take before the misfire starts up? What exactly are the two codes you talk about?

Comment: I'm not sure of the codes and yes I runs good when first started but after about 5 mins of running it starts misfiring and a lot more while in gear it jumps and bucks and acts like it wants to stall

Comment: Do you have the capability to move coils between cylinders? If so, change out the #3 coil with one of the other coils and see if the symptom follows the coil or stays on the #3 cylinder. If it stays, it's not the coil. If it follows it, then replace the coil.

Comment: OK will do than you

Answer (score 1):

Your car has one or more of the following problems, likely limited to just that cylinder.

1. **Not enough spark** - This could be caused by a defective ignition coil or defective wiring. You could replace the coil or swap it with another one
2. **Too much fuel** - This could be caused by a sticking fuel injector or defective wiring
3. **Coolant entering the combustion chamber** - A damaged headgasket could result in coolant entering the combustion chamber. This would cause a misfire condition when hot. If the car is consuming coolant as you drive then this may be the problem. Generally speaking, the coolant system develops and abnormally high amount of pressure as well.